# How do we find the table row containing a specific text when "data-row-index" is not explicitly given

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use the following code to locate the table row containing the text.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),'Row 1, Column 1')]]")); 
String dataRowIndex = table.getAttribute("data-row-index");
System.out.println(dataRowIndex);
```

I am using this site

```
String URL="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tables.htm";
driver.navigate().to(URL);
```

with following html codes.

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1px;">
<tr>
<td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
<td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
<td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It is returning null since there is no "data-row-index" explicitly given. How can we identify the row number in the table.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this row index property to identify the row number.

```
String dataRowIndex = table.getAttribute("rowIndex");
```

This gives results without iterating the entire table.

Comment: For future reference, you can use cellIndex for the column number